# How persist with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class named "Token Requestor" and "Certificates". Each Token Requestor have many Certificates and Certificates have **only one** Token Requestor.

TokenRequestor.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TOKEN_REQUESTOR")
public class TokenRequestor implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TOKEN_REQUESTOR_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "TOKEN_REQUESTOR_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "TOKEN_REQUESTOR_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "TOKEN_REQUESTOR_ID")
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tokenRequestorId")
    private List<Certificate> certificates;
```

Certificate.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CERTIFICATES")
public class Certificate {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CERTIFICATES_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SQ_CERTIFICATES_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "CERTIFICATES_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "CERTIFICATES_ID")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TOKEN_REQUESTOR_ID")
    private TokenRequestor tokenRequestorId;    //Foreign key*/
```

When I insert a Token Requestor, they certificate must be create. They are created but with TOKEN_REQUESTOR_ID null in Certificate table. Why this happens?

POST Token Requestor

```
{
    "domain": "GTW",
    ...,
    "certificates": [
    {
      "usage": "ENC",
      "alias": "encryption_cert",
      "content": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ... -----END CERTIFICATE-----"
    },
    {
      "usage": "DEC",
      "alias": "decryption_cert",
      "content": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ... -----END CERTIFICATE-----"
    },
    {
      "usage": "SSL",
      "alias": "communication_cert",
      "content": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ... -----END CERTIFICATE-----"
    },
    {
      "usage": "CA",
      "alias": "TSP ROOT CA",
      "content": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ... -----END CERTIFICATE-----"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you define the relationship to be bidirectional, which basically means each side of the relation should have reference to the other side.

lets say we have TokenRequestor  object , this object has two Certificates, this would be enough only if the relation is unidirectional ( which you can turn your relation to to solve this issue btw), for a bidirectional relation you need to haveeach one of the Certificate holding a reference to their TokenReguestor.

Comment: I have a /tokenRequestor resource and /certificates resource, certificate can be created in both resources. Unidirectional relationship resolve in this case?

Comment: @DanielaMorais either you will have to retried and inject TokenRequestor in Certificate or make the relation a Unidirectional by removing ManyToOne(and its reference) and put the joinColumn in the none owningentity (where the OneToMany)